# Google Cloud SQL -“Instance is being updated” more than 2 days

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

SQL Server instance has got stuck almost 3 days ago while deleting an user, Google Cloud SQL is still showing "Instance is being updated".

What can I do to stop it?

[image]

Comment: I think that this is a customer support question if you are in free trial or if you are paying for support you can open a [chat](https://console.cloud.google.com/support/chat) with an agent; otherwise it is necessary to file a ticket using a [public issue tracker](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers)

Answer (score 1):

Funny that you mention it, because I am experiencing the exact same thing.
I tried to add a user last Friday. Ever since then the operating is stuck.

If you use the Gcloud SDK you can find more details about why the operation is hanging:

```
gcloud sql operations list -instance <instance-name>
```

You will receive a list of all the completed and running operations.
You can get further details about a operation by running the following command:

```
gcloud sql operations describe <operation-ID> --verbosity debug
```

I wonder whether you got the same output as me:

```
  errors:
  - code: ERROR_SQL_SERVER_EXTERNAL_WARNING
    kind: sql#operationError
    message: "Warn: DeleteUser: DropUser SQL command failed with error mssql: Could\
      \ not drop login 'dbo' as the user is currently logged in."
```

Solution: I filed a bug at https://issuetracker.google.com/

They were able to create a private issue, and they asked me to supply the Project ID and the ID of the Cloud SQL instance.
After a few hours they cancelled the operation and the Cloud SQL instance was available again.

Comment: I'm going to check that, but could you disable billing? Because it's still running and generate billing.

Comment: I'd escalate to support. They could also likely help with the billing piece if you're being billed for an instance you aren't able to use.

Comment: Support cancelled the operation for me. There was no way of doing that on my own.